# Best cache time Laravel for content

Tags: php, laravel

I have a question. What time I need pass in Cache for more posts? I have code on MainController:

```
$posts = Cache::rememberForever('posts', function() {
    return Post::active()->paginate(15);
});

return view('posts', compact('posts);
```

Can I cache on forever?

**Note**: In my Post model I have global observers: `created`, `deleted`, `updated`, `saved`. In all these observers I do: `Cache::forget('posts')`. How will be best? Cache forever or cache posts on time (10 min). Help me please decide. Posts very active adding... Interval: 10, 20, 30 mins

Answer (score 1):

Generally you should cache for as long as possible, to maximize page load speed, but not much longer than you expect new content to show up... Otherwise no one will see the new content.

You could cache for 10 or 30 minutes, because you only add new posts every 10-30 minutes.

If you cache forever, you will not see any new posts after caching. Unless you manually clear the caches.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to decide based on the business domain and requirement, what value realtime post will hold vs a post shown after a delay of cache expiry.

For example, if its a normal blog then probably not showing it immediately after its created and having it in cache once the current cache is purged may be good. If it's a real time stock application, then each second delay matters.

Depending on users active, number of posts added per hour you can decide a soft spot for the cache remember time. May be in your case 20-30 mins would be good. There is no standard ideal time to hold a value in cache.

Also sometimes you can avoid forgetting/purging the cache for not-so important reasons. For example you have 100 posts cached, and one post is deleted. You can avoid rebuilding the 99 post cache but have the 100th deleted post in cache. When user clicks on it to go to its detail page, you can say page you requests is no longer available. Similarly for updates etc.